# Error on google app script "TypeError: Cannot call method append row..)"

Tags: google-apps-script

I am a junior high school student and I am a beginner on using "Google App Script". Please help me in this line of code because I keep on getting error "TypeError: Cannot call method "appendRow" of null. (line 29, file "Code", project "AS_Score")". Here is my line of code:

```
function doGet(e){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gk1O4SkS09f96si3trbS0HcVRhXlQH5wc7LVCJ-xMus/edit#gid=0");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  addUser(e,sheet);


}


function doPost(e){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gk1O4SkS09f96si3trbS0HcVRhXlQH5wc7LVCJ-xMus/edit#gid=0");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  addUser(e,sheet);

}



function addUser(e,sheet) {

  var id = e.parameter.id;
  var name = e.parameter.name;
  var grade = e.parameter.grade;
  var subject = e.parameter.subject;
  var score = e.parameter.score;

  sheet.appendRow([id,name,grade,subject,score]);

}
```

Please help me if I have any error, thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that you are getting all the values in `e`?

Comment: Are you posting this from a web app?

Comment: It is saying that there is something wrong with the sheet. My guess is that it can't find the sheet and is returning an empty value, this could be for two reasons: 
1) The name of the sheet is incorrect (it is case sensitive)
2) The URL of the SpreadSheet is not correct - try leaving out the "#gid=0"

I would suggest using Logger.log(sheet) and see what it says, if it does not say sheet then it is the sheet, if not replace the var sheet for ss. 

Try those first and let us know how you get on and we can help more from there!

Answer (score 1):

try changing the name of your sheet to: ("Sheet1");